# Case When Statement for Netsuite Report

Tags: case, netsuite

I am having an issue with a Case Statement, this is being used in a Saved Search for Netsuite but the reporting DB runs off Oracle. We are calculating Net Promoter Score (NPS) based on a question from our Customer Surveys. Below is a working example:

```
SUM(Case When {custrecord_rsm_csf_rec} = 'Very Likely' Then 1 Else 0 End - 
Case When {custrecord_rsm_csf_rec} = 'Neither Likely or Unlikely' Then 1 
When {custrecord_rsm_csf_rec} = 'Unlikely' then 1 
When {custrecord_rsm_csf_rec} = 'Very Unlikely' then 1 Else 0 End)
/count({internalid})
```

What I am trying to do is add the to_char({created}), 'MM') = xx to group the results in month to month buckets on the returned result. I have am having no luck after many different attempts that all look something like below:

```
SUM(Case When {custrecord_rsm_csf_rec} = 'Very Likely' AND 
to_char({created}), 'MM') = 03 Then 1 Else 0 End - 
Case When {custrecord_rsm_csf_rec} = 'Neither Likely or Unlikely' AND 
to_char({created}), 'MM') = 03 Then 1 
When {custrecord_rsm_csf_rec} = 'Unlikely' AND to_char({created}), 'MM') = 
03 then 1 
When {custrecord_rsm_csf_rec} = 'Very Unlikely' AND to_char({created}), 
'MM') = 03 then 1 Else 0 End)
/count({internalid})
```

Any assistance pointing me toward my Syntax/Logical errors would be much appreciated.

Comment: What response do you get from the system when you execute your statement?

Comment: In the statement above you're closing the `to_char()` too early.  It should be `to_char({created}, 'MM')` but you have an extra `)` after `{created}`

Comment: Thanks Krypton, if I correct that I can return a number but it is the wrong number unfortunately. Somewhere in there the logical math is wrong it seems.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you're getting / what you expect?

Comment: I have made progress on this and have one final piece to fix..

SUM(Case When ({custrecord_rsm_csf_rec} = 'Very Likely' AND to_char({created}, 'MM') = 03) Then 1 Else 0 End -   
Case  When({custrecord_rsm_csf_rec} = 'Neither Likely or Unlikely' AND to_char({created}, 'MM') = 03)  
OR ({custrecord_rsm_csf_rec} = 'Unlikely' AND to_char({created}, 'MM') = 03)  
OR ({custrecord_rsm_csf_rec} = 'Very Unlikely' AND to_char({created}, 'MM') = 03) then 1 Else 0 End)/count({internalid})

The last part I need to do is add the same date function to the end /count to get the right math out of it.